# C++ DLL библиотеки

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, lib

Недавно я решил создать собственную динамически подключаемую библиотеку или иными словами `dll`. Я пока таким не занимался. Мое задание заключается в том, что я ввожу квадратную матрицу и число `k`. Делю `k-ю` строку на диагональный элемент этой строки. А потом вывожу исходную и полученную. И для этой задачи мне надо использовать класс и подключать мою библиотеку динамически. Вот моя реализация на `visual studio`(там при создании проекта я выбрал библиотеку `dll`). Некоторые вещи при создании `dll` я смотрел на форуме `microsoft`.

Компилятор не запускает программу по этой причине:
Предупреждение  `C4273  matrix::matrix::matrix: несовместимая компоновка dll`. По мимо этого появляется окно: Не удалось запустить программу. Не поддерживаемая операция. Неизвестная ошибка: `0x800700c1.`

Помогите решить проблему.

lib.h

```
#pragma once
#ifdef MATRIXDLL_EXPORTS
#define MATRIXDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATRIXDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace matrix
{
    class matrix
    {
        int **p, m, n;
        public:
        MATRIXDLL_API matrix(int row, int col);

        //    ~matrix()
        //    {
        //       delete [] p;
        //    }

        MATRIXDLL_API void accept();
        MATRIXDLL_API void display();
        MATRIXDLL_API void test();
    };
}
```

lib.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "lib.h"
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;
namespace matrix
{
    matrix::matrix(int row, int col)
    {
        m = row;
        n = col;
        p = new int*[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        {
            p[i] = new int[n];
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                p[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    void matrix::accept()
    {
        cout << "Enter matrix elements: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                cin >> p[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    void matrix::display()
    {
        cout << "The matrix is:\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                cout << p[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    void matrix::test()
    {
        int K;
        cout << "Enter k: " << endl;
        cin >> K;
        display();
        int R = p[K - 1][K - 1];
        cout << endl;
        for (int d = 0; d < m; d++)
        {
            p[K - 1][d] = p[K - 1][d] / K;
        }
        display();
    }
}
```

dllmain.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
        DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
        LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Так важнее, КАК вы ее создавали - компонуя динамический, статический рантайм, например - и как использующее приложение.

Comment: @Harry я пытался создать динамический. Кстати когда я делал через статический, создавая новый проект то выдавалась ошибка: использование ключевого слова "static" не допускается.

Comment: код ошибки 800700с1 - это "%1 is not a valid Win32 application. ". Вы не пытаетесь запустить dll?

Comment: @KoVadim я создавал отдельно проект подключая свою dll. Выдает компилятор такую ошибку: 
Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall matrix::matrix::matrix(int,int)" (__imp_??0matrix@0@QAE@HH@Z) в функции _main

Comment: Это не ошибка компилятора. это ошибка запуска приложения.

Comment: @KoVadim Ааа ок. А как тогда мне запускать?

Comment: поправка к моему коменту - 800700с1  - это ошибка запуска, LNK2019  - это ошибка линковки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем огромное спасибо!!! Все работает. Забыл, что при подключении библиотеки в проект нужно добавить object file library